# Bootstrap navigation bar text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my head text "*PCT Research*" on the center.

**Here is the code I want to use:**

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-header {
     float: none;
}
```

But it is coming from online bootstrap where online it is: `float: right;`. I want to override that. How can I do it with online linking of bootstrap?

To see the full view of the nav here is the link:
http://codepen.io/Rehman/pen/vOwmNy

Comment: Just be sure to call your custom CSS after you've called Bootstrap, then your CSS will override Bootstrap's.

Comment: @APAD1 i have linked main.css file after the online MDSN Bootstrap does it mean i'm calling it after? if yes then i have done that and its isn't working

Comment: Thats because your media quey is malformed, you're missing an opening and closing {}

Comment: @APAD1 if i'm just calling my custom css after then it doesn't work but if i use `!important` it does work. And yea i just removed the media query after important its working fine without that

Comment: As I mentioned on the other 2 posts, using `!important` is bad practice and should be avoided at all costs and it is certainly not necessary for your issue. The problem, as I mentioned before, is that your media query is malformed. If you fix the media query and load your custom CSS after Bootstrap then it will work just fine.

Comment: right...i have changed the linking after and it worked as well. THANKS alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override this kind of bootstrap element, you should use the `!important` like following:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .navbar-header {
    float: none !important;
  }
}
```

It's actually working by doing this in your pen, as far as you also don't forget the `{ }` to your `@media` declaration.

You can find more information about the `!important` in the great article from *Chris Coyier* on *CSS Tricks*: [When Using !important is The Right Choice](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).

**EDIT:**

Considering the comment of *@APAD1* and in complement to the answer, **calling your CSS files in the right order** is a better way to fix your issue, in this case at least. So call *Bootstrap CSS* first, then your own *custom CSS*.

In the *Codepen* way, that means loading the Bootstrap CSS with "*Add External CSS*" in the properties of your *CSS window*, instead of loading it in the HTML.

Comment: Using `!important` should be avoided at all costs, in this case there is no need to use `!important`, you just need to call the custom CSS after the Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: @APAD1 That's also why I linked this article about that. I agree with the fact that it should be avoided *when possible*, but there is some situations where the overriding with `!important` is necessary, depending on the project and the specs. But you'r right about this case, the loading priority fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you must use '!important' like so:

```
 .navbar-header {
        float: none !important;
  }
```

this will override the class. however this is a quick way round it and can get messy going forward. another way is to call custom css after bootstrap css

Comment: Again, no reason to use `!important` here.

Answer (score 0):

To center it on all devices you must use a media query with a large max-width like so. Check it out on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdGmrZ). You can mess with the max-width

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1600px) {.navbar-brand {
  float: none!important;
  width: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-header {
  float: none!important;
}
}
```

Snippet:

```css
.navbar-collapse ul{
    margin-right: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 17px;
}



.navbar-header {

    width: 0%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1600px) {.navbar-brand {
  float: none!important;
  width: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-header {
  float: none!important;
}
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Research Group</title>

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/vendor/html5-3.6-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="menu" class="col-md">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <!-- The Logo button & menu toggle button-->
                <divc class="row">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">PCT Research group</a>
                    </div>
                </divc>
                <!--End button & logo -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html" target="_self"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html" target="_self"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Research</a>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="publications.html" target="_self"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
                                    Publications</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="projects.html" target="_self"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> Projects</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="News.html" target="_self"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>Events</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="Events.html" target="_self"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                News</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="Profiles_View.html" target="_self"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Knowledge
                                    Power </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html" target="_self"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alt"></span> About
                                    Us</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply i got it without using import, the calling was just not after the Maxcdn bootstrap.